# Textarea extra padding

Tags: css, google-chrome

I cant remove the extra padding above and below the textarea in google chrome

https://jsfiddle.net/y4fe39mr/1/

```
<td rowspan="3" class="biginputcell">
                        <textarea class="biginput" type="textarea" name="notes" id="notes" value=""></textarea>
                    </td>
```

I cannot figure out where the extra 15px padding is comming from in chrome.

```
.biginput{
    width:230px;
    height:150px;
    font-size:0px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0px;
    resize: none;
    display: block
}
.biginputcell{
    background-color:blue;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:160px;
}
```

I have accepted the answer pointing out the issue with `rowspan` because it was the direct fix to the issue.
However as one of the answers pointed out `div`s are the better way to make my form, I will be changing the form to `div` tags rather than an overly complicated table.

Comment: Try to `JSON.stringify()` the data object.

Comment: The file contains a JSON object which is what `[object Object]` means. What are you expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your column is `middle` aligned. If you align your `textarea` to the top, this won't happen.

I personally think there are too many unnecessary classes in your code. You should consider simplifying it. Also, I wouldn't recommend using table for structuring your forms. It can get quite confusing.

Here a suggestion for you.

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border: 0;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

.form {
  display: table;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.column {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.column + .column {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.form-group {
  display: table;
}

.form-group > * {
  display: table-cell;
}

.form-group + .form-group {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.label {
  color: white;
  font-size:15px;
  min-width: 60px;
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.input{
  width:230px;
  height:30px;
  resize: none;
}

.input.small {
  width: 90px;
}

.input.big {
  height: 150px;
}

.button{
  font-size:15px;
  height:90px;
  width:90px;
}
```

```html
<form action="edit.php" method="POST" class="form">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="label" for="time">Time:</label>
           <input class="input" type="text" name="time" id="time" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="label" for="events">Event:</label>
           <input class="input" type="text" name="events" id="events" value=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="label" for="notes">Notes:</label>
           <textarea class="input big" type="textarea" name="notes" id="notes" value=""></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="input small" id="preset" onchange="fillpreset(value)">
            <option value="0">PRESET</option>
            <option value="1">Pre Service</option>
            <option value="2">Worship</option>
            <option value="3">MC Bridge</option>
            <option value="4">Message AM</option>
            <option value="5">Message PM</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="button" type="submit" name="task" value="Go" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="button" type="submit" name="task" value="Clear" />
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input `middle top and bottom vertical align` all add the extra pixels in different positions, I have accepted the `rowspan` answer because it did fix the immediate issue. However i have decided that your method of using `div`s will give me better control as the table breaks when used on an ipad.

Answer (score 1):

Change the rowspan=3 to rowspan=4 in your markup for the elements with classes biglabelcell and biglabelinput
check the following code snippet

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
textarea {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.edittable{
 height:240px;
 width:400px;
 border-collapse:collapse;
 overflow:hidden;
 table-layout: fixed;
}
.labelcell{
 width:60px;
 height:40px;
 font-family:sans-serif;
 background-color:blue;
}
.label{
 width:50px;
 height:30px;
 font-size:20px;
 font-family:sans-serif;
}
.biglabel{
 width:50px;
 font-size:20px;
 font-family:sans-serif;
}
.biglabelcell{
 background-color:blue;
}
.inputcell{
 width:240px;
 background-color:blue;
}
.input{
 width:230px;
 height:30px;
 font-size:15px;
 font-family:sans-serif;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 border:0px;
}
.biginput{
 width:230px;
 height:150px;
 font-size:0px;
 font-family:sans-serif;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 border:0px;
 resize: none;
 display: block
}
.biginputcell{
 background-color:blue;
 vertical-align:middle;
 height:160px;
}
.selectcell{
 width:100px;
 height:40px;
 font-size:15px;
 font-family:sans-serif;
 background-color:blue;
}
.select{
 width:90px;
 height:30px;
 border:0px;
}
.buttoncell{
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
 background-color:blue;
}
.button{
 height:90px;
 width:90px;
 border:0px;
}
```

```html
  <form action="edit.php" method="POST">
   <table class="edittable">
    <tr>
     <td class="labelcell">
      <label class="label" for="time">Time:</label>
     </td>
     <td class="inputcell">
      <input class="input" type="text" name="time" id="time" value="" />
     </td>
     <td class="selectcell">
      <select class="select" id="preset" onchange="fillpreset(value)">
       <option value="0">PRESET</option>
       <option value="1">Pre Service</option>
       <option value="2">Worship</option>
       <option value="3">MC Bridge</option>
       <option value="4">Message AM</option>
       <option value="5">Message PM</option>
      </select>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="labelcell">
      <label class="label" for="events">Event:</label>
     </td>
     <td class="inputcell">
      <input class="input" type="text" name="events" id="events" value=""/>
     </td>
     <td rowspan="2" class="buttoncell">      
      <input class="button" type="submit" name="task" value="Go" />
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td rowspan="4" class="biglabelcell">
      <label class="biglabel" for="notes">Notes:</label>
     </td>
     <td rowspan="4" class="biginputcell">
      <textarea class="biginput" type="textarea" name="notes" id="notes" value=""></textarea>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td rowspan="2" class="buttoncell">  
      <input class="button" type="submit" name="task" value="Clear" />
     </td>
    </tr>
```

Hope this helps. If not can you please explain how the page should look like a snapshot would be helpful

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the obvious I kept rereading the code and kept missing it.